# Are the properties of map holding for the restriction or the composition?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces.

For any map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and any subset $S\subseteq Y$, we let $f_{S}$ to denote the map from $f^{-1}(S)$ to $S$ which maps $x\in f^{-1}(S)$ to $f(x)$.

Consider the following items:
(a) continuous map, 
(b) closed map,
(c) open map,
(d) homeomorphism, 
(e) embedding.

Consider the following two statements:

(1) If $f$ is a ___, then so is $f_{W}$ for every open subset $W$ of $Y$.

(2) For any open cover $V_{j}$ $(j\in J)$ of $Y$, if $f_{V_{j}}$ is a ___ for every $j\in J$, then so is $f$.

Answer for (1) and (2), which among the items listed above, when put into ___, will make the statement hold.

I have proved that the answer of (1) is abcde, and the answer of (2) have bc.

My question is if a, d, or e holds for (2).

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Suppose $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, then $C=\bigcup_{j\in J}(C \cap f^{-1}(V_{j}))$. $f(C)=\bigcup_{j\in J}f(C \cap f^{-1}(V_{j}))=\bigcup_{j\in J}(f(C )\cap V_{j})$. We want to show that $f(C)$ is closed, it is equal to say that $Y-f(C)$ is open. $Y-f(C)=\bigcup_{j\in J}(V_{j})-\bigcup_{j\in J}(f(C )\cap V_{j})=\bigcup_{j\in J}(V_{j}-f(C))$. It suffices to show that $V_{j}-f(C)$ is open for all $j$. For any point $x$ in $V_{j}-f(C)$, we find some $k\in J$ such that $x\in V_{k}$, then $x$ is contained in an open subset $V_{k}-f(C)$ of $Y$.

Comment: Can I ask you how to prove that a, d, and e hold for (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To find counterexamples to (a), (d), and (e), try taking $Y$ to be a discrete space and each $V_j$ to be a singleton.